# Cross antimeridian 180° in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some Meteorological fields from a Grib2 file and I have a problem. How can I cross Antimeridian 180° in Matplotlib ? When I set the first lon = 160 and second lon = -40, Python returns me an error:

TypeError: Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, but has shape (101, 0)

Does anyone know how to solve that problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code - preferably a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: As above - there are quite a few ways to plot geographic data in matplotlib, so we have no idea which one you are trying to use here.